# skipping ":" in ansible with strings already having ""(quotation)

Tags: ansible

i am trying to use **lineinfile:** to replace a whole line but when executing it complains about : (colon)  i tried using " (quotation) but i think ansible to not able to differentiate between existing "" and added "" even tried \ to escape colon but still not working

```
lineinfile:
 dest='/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0'
 state=present
 regexp=^TEAM_CONFIG=.*
 line=TEAM_CONFIG='{"runner": {"name": "{{item.bondmode}}"}, "link_watch": {"name": "ethtool"}}'
with_items:
- "{{ teaming }}"
```

Comment: note using `lineinfile` is a bit of code smell; you'll end up much better off if you switch to `template`.

Comment: @tedder42 i just want to replace that string,wont template replace whole file?

Comment: yes, you'd need to safe save the whole file. There are advantages to adding the config to your repo- not just for idempotency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with space after colon:

```
line="TEAM_CONFIG={'runner':{'name':'{{item.bondmode}}'}, 'link_watch':{'name':'ethtool'}}"
```

will work (It does not look good but is still a valid json), see also [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/1341)

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion i forgot to mention that in question,i tried that too and playbook works but the purpose is not working,it simply fails without those spaces.

Comment: First of all I would enclose all the stuff with '=' signs in quotes (which would make the whole thing more readable, see 'line' in answer), but i don't think this is the problem. What is the error message then?

Comment: its working now using ' instead of " was causing issue and not because of space.
'TEAM_CONFIG={"runner":{"name":"{{item.bondmode}}"}, "link_watch":{"name":"ethtool"}}'
thanks